# Validating input in foreach loop before updating multiple rows

Tags: php

I have multiple table rows output with values populated from a database.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name='edit_ativity[]'>
           <option value="11" selected="selected">Aerobic Dancing - Low Impact</option>
           <option value="12">Aerobic Dancing - Strenuously</option>
           <option value="13">Aerobics - High Impact</option>
           <option value="19">Skipping - Slow</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
          <input type='text' name='edit_duration[]' value='100' />
     </td>
     <td>
          <input type='text' class='datepicker' name='edit_datepicker[]' value='2019-03-01' id=''>
     </td>
</tr>
An other Row 
An other Row
```

The user can change the values on each of the row fields then submit the form which updates the database with the new values.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['edit_ativity'] as $key=>$value) {
        $dist_activity_id = $_POST['edit_ativity'][$key];
        $dist_activity_duration = $_POST['edit_duration'][$key];
        $dist_id = $_POST['distance_id'][$key];
        $dist_date = $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key];                   
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE distance SET dist_activity_id=$dist_activity_id, dist_activity_duration=$dist_activity_duration, dist_date='$dist_date' WHERE id=$dist_id");
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

What I need help with is only executing the update command none of fields are empty.

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want to update all rows where none of the fields are empty, or prevent form submission altogether if any fields are empty in the entire table?

Comment: I don't want to update any fields. I'd like to output a message telling the visitor there are errors.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: I'm using mysqli

Comment: Just asking stupidly: what keeps you from checking for that condition? Using `isset` or `empty`, this should not be too hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do another `isset()` for all the fields you want to be not empty inside the loop

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['edit_ativity'] as $key=>$value) {
        if (isset($_POST['edit_ativity'][$key],
                  $_POST['edit_duration'][$key],
                  $_POST['distance_id'][$key], 
                  $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key])
        ){
            $dist_activity_id = $_POST['edit_ativity'][$key];
            $dist_activity_duration = $_POST['edit_duration'][$key];
            $dist_id = $_POST['distance_id'][$key];
            $dist_date = $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key];                   
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE distance SET dist_activity_id=$dist_activity_id, dist_activity_duration=$dist_activity_duration, dist_date='$dist_date' WHERE id=$dist_id");
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

> I should also point out that Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
> Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

#### Assuming you are using the `mysqli_` API

This code would protect you against SQL Injection and be easier to read as well.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['edit_ativity'] as $key=>$value) {
        if (isset($_POST['edit_ativity'][$key], 
                  $_POST['edit_duration'][$key],
                  $_POST['distance_id'][$key], 
                  $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key])
        ){
              
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE distance SET 
                                        dist_activity_id=?,
                                        dist_activity_duration=?, 
                                        dist_date=? 
                                    WHERE id=?");

            $stmt->bind_param('iisi',$_POST['edit_ativity'][$key],
                                     $_POST['edit_duration'][$key],
                                     $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key],
                                     $_POST['distance_id'][$key]
                            );
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Get the error when updating Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

Comment: Woops I missed a Comma after `dist_activity_id=?,` try again

Comment: There was a missing , after SET dist_activity_id=?

Comment: Posted before I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to validate all the input before updating the values you can do this by:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['edit_ativity'] as $key=>$value) {
        $dist_activity_id = $_POST['edit_ativity'][$key];
        $dist_activity_duration = $_POST['edit_duration'][$key];
        $dist_id = $_POST['distance_id'][$key];
        $dist_date = $_POST['edit_datepicker'][$key];   
        // Validation//
            // if one or more inputs are empty inside the if wont run//
        if (!empty($dist_activity_id) && !empty($dist_activity_duration) && !empty($dist_id) && !empty($dist_date)) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE distance SET dist_activity_id=$dist_activity_id, dist_activity_duration=$dist_activity_duration, dist_date='$dist_date' WHERE id=$dist_id");
            $stmt->execute();
        }              

    }

    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```